# Dynamic Semantic UI dropdown not being submitted with form

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-select, dropdown, semantic-ui

So I'm trying to create a dynamic [Semantic UI Dropdown](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html). For the example I have below, the dropdown for **Species** is initially blank but when you select a **Protocol**, an AJAX request is made and returns a new set of options for the next dropdown (Species).

```js
function initDropdowns() {
  $(".ui.dropdown").dropdown({
    allowAdditions: false,
    fullTextSearch: true,
    onChange: function(value, text, choice) {
      if ($(this).data("type") == "protocol") {
        var menu = $(".species.ui.dropdown").find(".menu");

        menu.empty();
        menu.append("<div class='item' data-value='1'>Mice</div><div class='item' data-value='2'>Rats</div><div class='item' data-value='3'>Guinea Pigs</div>"); // This comes from an AJAX request

        initDropdowns();
      }
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  initDropdowns();

  $(document).on("click", "button", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($("form").serialize());
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}

form .ui.dropdown {
  min-height: 1em !important;
  height: 1em !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.7/components/dropdown.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.7/components/dropdown.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.7/components/transition.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.7/components/transition.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<form action="test.php" method="post">
  <select name="protocol" class="protocol ui fluid search dropdown required" data-type="protocol" data-default="Protocol">
    <option value="">Protocol</option>
    <option value="123">SAM-123</option>
    <option value="456">SAM-456</option>
  </select>

  <select name="species" class="species ui fluid search dropdown required" data-type="species" data-default="Species">
    <option value="">Species</option>
  </select>

  <button>Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

This seems to be working fine in terms of dynamically populating the dropdown options but when I submit the form after making all my selections the data passed to the server doesn't include the `species`.

Comment: Oh darn.. Not really sure but I think I know what the problem is. When I call `$("form").serialize();` it's looking at the actual `select` element and not the `div` that acts as the custom dropdown - which I didn't update with the new options from the AJAX result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

index.php :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
                function populate() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/populate.php',
                        success: function(data) {
                            var species = JSON.parse(data);
                            $('#species').dropdown({
                       placeholder: "species",
                                values: species,
                                fullTextSearch: true,
                            });
                            return data;
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert('error of ajax, populate anyway just to show');
                            var species = JSON.parse('[{"name" : "Mice", "value" : "1"}, {"name" : "Rats", "value" : "2"}, {"name" : "Guinea Pigs", "value" : "3"}]');
                            $('#species').dropdown({
                       placeholder: "species",
                                values: species,
                                fullTextSearch: true,
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                
                var protocol = [{"name" : "SAM-123", "value" : "123"}, {"name" : "SAM-456", "value" : "456"}];
                $('#protocol').dropdown({
              placeholder: "Protocol",
                    values: protocol,
                    fullTextSearch: true,
                });
                
                populate();
                
                $(document).on("click", "button", function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log($("form").serialize());
                        var e = $(".form").form('get values'); /*https://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html*/
                        console.log("i manipulate the protocol value : " + e.protocol);
                        console.log("i manipulate the species value : " + e.species);
                });
            });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!-- Semantic UI -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.14/semantic.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.14/semantic.min.css"  />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="ui form" action="post.php" method="post">
         <div class="field">
          <label>Protocol</label>
          <div id="protocol" class="protocol ui search labeled selection dropdown">
           <input name="protocol" type="hidden"> <!-- store the selected value that gonna be posted -->
           <span class="text"></span>
           <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          </div>
         </div>
         
         <div class="field">
          <label>Species</label>
          <div id="species" class="species ui search labeled selection dropdown">
           <input name="species" type="hidden"> <!-- store the selected value that gonna be posted -->
           <span class="text"></span>
           <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          </div>
         </div>
         
         <button type="submit" class="ui fluid teal submit button">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

populate.php :

```
<?php
    echo '[{"name" : "Mice", "value" : "1"}, {"name" : "Rats", "value" : "2"}, {"name" : "Guinea Pigs", "value" : "3"}]';
?>
```